# API response is undefined when used, but not when console.log()

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, undefined, use-effect

I am trying to display data from https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets.
I am getting the data in console, but when I try to display it in return() the data becomes undefined.

`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

```
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets')
            .then(function (response) {
                setApiData(response.data.data)
                //console.log(response.data.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }, [])

console.log(apiData)
    return (
        <>
            {/*{apiData[0].id}*/}
        </>
    )
};
```

I think that it is the useEffect that I need to run again after the page has rendered?

Comment: State Hooks (in your example `setApiData()`) are _asynchronous_ - it is not being set immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should check if your array has data. By the way I didn't check the code, it will be something like this.

```
return (
    <>
      {apiData && apiData.length !== 0 ? apiData[0].id : "Please wait while fetching..."}
    </>
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked, can you explain why checking if the array has data made it work?

Comment: As @Jax-p mentioned in your question comment section, your 'axios.get' method is asynchronous. So when you render your page, 'apiData[0].id' is not fetched yet because of asynchronous method need some time to fetch data from network. We put 'apiData && apiData.length' control means that "Render on page  apiData[0].id if I have apiData array and this array's lenght not equal to zero".

Comment: By the way, please check my message as proper answer so other users can get help from it.

Comment: Thanks! I was going to but stackoverflow has a timer so I had to wait. @shadowman_93